# Omega Notation in Explanation of Chain Rule

Tags: multivariable-calculus, notation, ordinals

In his book Multivariate Calculus and Geometry, Sean Dineen explains the chain rule as follows:

[image]

I understood well enough his point but, then he goes on to introduce an unknown and unexplained $\omega$ to explain something having to do with the unit basis:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with ordinals. Here $\omega$ is a vector, and $\omega_j$ is its $j$th coordinate. It's entirely analogous to saying $a = (a_1, a_2, a_3)$, which we could also write as $a = a_1 \hat{i} + a_2 \hat{j} + a_3 \hat{k}$ if you're familiar with that notation. In multiple dimensions, instead of using letters we use $e_i$ to denote the $i$th standard basis vector, so we would write $a = a_1 e_1 + a_2 e_2 + a_3 e_3 = \sum_i a_i e_i$. Your book is doing exactly the same thing but with $\omega$.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: What a relief to know they are only the n-components of a vector! I was having nightmares about infinitely summing objects. Thank you for your answer.